# How to rename a geopackage table in Python?

Tags: qgis, python, geopackage

I'm trying to rename a geopackage table from a QGIS 3.8.0 Python processing script.

But it leaves a broken dataset in 2 parts, where the tabular data table has been renamed but leaves the geometry table not renamed.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import sqlite3

geopPath = r"C:\GIS\Processing\Tool Processing\NaturalEarth2.gpkg

tab = 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries'

newTab = 'nev_10m_admin_0_countries'

con = sqlite3.connect(geopPath)

cursor = con.cursor()

query01 = "ALTER TABLE '{}' RENAME TO '{}';".format(tab,newTab)

query02 = "UPDATE {} SET table_name = '{}' WHERE table_name = '{}';".format('gpkg_ogr_contents',newTab,tab)

query03 = "UPDATE {} SET table_name = '{}' WHERE table_name = '{}';".format('gpkg_geometry_columns',newTab,tab)

cursor.execute(query01)

cursor.execute(query02)

cursor.execute(query03)

con.commit()

cursor.close()

con.close()
```

That seems to commit without error. And I suspect query 01 and 02 are doing the same thing.

I don't think editing the gpkg_geometry_columns is needed as it's only a tablename change, the CRS remains the same.

This [link](http://cite.opengeospatial.org/pub/cite/files/edu/geopackage/text/advanced.html#why-does-geopackage-have-these-tables) is quite useful but can't find the part that helps me.

Which columns in which tables in the underlying geopackage structure do I need to edit?